# Позиционирование верхнего меню

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
  color: #8c8f94;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
}

.header-bg {
  background-image: url(images/bg/header.png);
  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 45% 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.layout {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.burger-menu div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #1b1c1e;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

.logo a {
  color: black !important;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.top-menu {
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1170px;
}

.top-menu .burger-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.top-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #26272d;
}

.help {
  color: #8c8f94;
}

.top-menu span {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.top-menu span:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}

.menu2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-bg">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="burger-menu">
        <div class="burger-menu-top"></div>
        <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
        <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu1">
        <span><a href="#">Tour</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Features</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Pricing</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>New</span>Providence</a></div>
      <div class="menu2">
        <span><a href="#"><span class="help">Help</span></a>
        </span>
        <span><a href="#">Contacts</a></span>
        <span><button><a href="#">Get  App</a></button></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Бургер-меню стоит чуть выше других элементов. Попытка использовать `margin` не приводит к результатам.

Если задать `position: absolute` сдвигается все что находится в `top-menu`. Почему меню так себя ведет?

Comment: Вопрос очень общий, и скрин очень маленький.

Comment: исправил.......

Comment: мне интересно как оно делается а не что бы его другие сделали мне)

Comment: @Vlad467, делается html + js + css + svg. Общий вопрос - общий ответ.

Comment: я бы сделал не будь бы у этого вопроса -3 жаль

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, почему нет? У вопроса минус, а не у Вас.

Comment: @Other мне тоже дадут минусов

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, хороший, годный ответ не минусуют даже в плохом вопросе.

Comment: @Other хорошо убедили щас  сделаю :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, но не я решаю что считать хорошим :) Но делайте - для этого мы тут собрались!

Comment: На самом деле ничего сложно нет, взять готовый слайдер, тот же "Slick Slider", с вертикальной прокруткой и поиграться с внешним видом. Это если свой скрипт будет лень писать. Я никак не проголосовал за вопрос. С одной стороны на результат было бы интересно посмотреть, а с другой стороны - автор мог бы потрудиться хотя бы код добавить, чтоб при ответе не нужно было самому разметку описывать целиком. Если вопрос общий, то ответ там чуть выше уже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите

```
.top-menu .burger-menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

И добавьте в `.burger-menu`:

```
position: absolute;
```

Да, и чтобы выровнять `.menu2`, нужно убрать `margin-top: -10px;`.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Lato;
}

html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
    color: #8c8f94;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Varela Round';
}

.header-bg {
    background-image: url(images/bg/header.png);
    height: 1000px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 45% 50%;   
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;    
}

.layout {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.burger-menu div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #1b1c1e;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;   
}

.logo a {
    color: black !important;
}

.logo span {
    font-weight: 900;
}
.top-menu {
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1170px;
}

.top-menu  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #26272d;
}

.help {
  color: #8c8f94;
}

.top-menu span {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.top-menu span:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
}
.menu2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.burger-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-bg">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="top-menu">
            <div class="burger-menu">
                <div class="burger-menu-top"></div>
                <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
                <div class="burger-menu-middle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu1">
                <span><a href="#">Tour</a></span>
                <span><a href="#">Features</a></span>
                <span><a href="#">Pricing</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>New</span>Providence</a></div>
            <div class="menu2">
                <span><a href="#"><span class="help">Help</span></a></span>
                <span><a href="#">Contacts</a></span>
                <span><button><a href="#">Get  App</a></button></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```